# base64encode in Nomad job file not encoding value of variable

Tags: terraform, hcl, nomad

I'm trying to store the result of a `base64encode` inside an `env` block like so:

```
env {
  HOST_ID = "${base64encode("${NOMAD_ADDR_serviceA}")}"
}
```

Which results in `HOST_ID` holding the base64 encoded string "${NOMAD_ADDR_serviceA}" and not the value of `NOMAD_ADDR_serviceA` as I had hoped. E.g. `HOST_ID = JHtOT01BRF9BRERSX3NlcnZpY2VBfQ==`.

I have also tried:

```
env {
  HOST_ID = base64encode("${NOMAD_ADDR_serviceA}")
}
```

... but this generates the same encoding.

Any idea how I can reach the expected outcome? Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: I've also tried the following:

```
HOST_ID = "${base64encode(NOMAD_ADDR_serviceA)}"
```

but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@apollo13](https://github.com/apollo13) over on the [Nomad Gitter](https://gitter.im/hashicorp-nomad/Lobby) figured out a way to delay the execution of `base64encode` for runtime interpolation using [Nomad templates](https://www.nomadproject.io/docs/job-specification/template). They recommend using something like:

```
template {
    data        = "HOST_ID={{ env \"NOMAD_ADDR_ServiceA\" | base64Encode }}"
    env         = true
    destination = "secrets/env"
}
```

Which works exactly as intended! Surprised to see that `base64encode` doesn't wait for the variable to become available.